# How to play both audio tracks on top of each other in windows

Tags: windows-7, audio, video

I have a recording of a video conference in quicktime format (.mov). It has the audio in two separate tracks, one for each end of the conversation.

If I play the video in vlc or the Windows default video player, I can choose which audio track to hear. How can I play the video so I can hear both audio tracks at the same time?

If I use the old and unsupported [quicktime](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL837?locale=en_GB) player it does work but that is a security risk now that Apple is not releasing updates to the software.

Comment: Are you saying you have 3 files, one video, and two audio?

Comment: @Dave No it's one .mov file. It just has two audio tracks.

Comment: so what happens when you try playing the file with QuickTime?

Comment: @MusselmanLLC You can choose which of the two tracks you want to hear. But I want to hear both.  The software package quicktime doesn't exist any more for Windows does it? See https://support.apple.com/kb/DL837?locale=en_GB

Comment: Are you saying you've tried using QuickTime?

Comment: @Dave See question update.

Comment: @Dave Not really as that software is old, out of date, unsupported and a potential security risk as a result.

Comment: https://www.5kplayer.com/video-music-player/free-mov-video-player.htm looks like it has some conversion options but I've never used it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Apple software is EOF and if you can't find other software which does this for you, then an option is to

1. Download some video editing software
2. Export the audio tracks from the audio
3. Download some audio editing software
4. Mix both audio tracks to a single stereo track, suggesting you pan to keep the conversation clear
5. Re-add this new audio to the original video